# VBA - elseif statement skipping "ElseIf"

Tags: vba, if-statement, nested-if

In the following code, the code works, but skips the "else if" line: `ElseIf y = "BAS" then "Basingstoke"`.

Since Basingstoke follows Belfast in the array from which the Ys come, it retains "Belfast" as the "Region" value. It works fine, but simply skips the `ElseIf` line entirely and goes to the "end if" immediately after.

I have a strong feeling I'm missing something obvious here...

```
For x = MinDate To MaxDate
    With salesr
        Set FindRng = .Find(What:=x, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then
                RowNumber = FindRng.Row
                FindRng.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, 39).ClearContents
                For Each y In RegionsArray
                    With Regions
                        Set FindRng2 = .Find(What:=y, _
                                             LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                             Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                             SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                             SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                             MatchCase:=False)
                             If Not FindRng2 Is Nothing Then
                                ColLeft = FindRng2.Column
                                ColRight = FindRng2.Column + 1
                                result = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Import.Range("S:S"), Import.Range("M:M"), x, Import.Range("O:O"), y)
                                result1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Import.Range("T:T"), Import.Range("M:M"), x, Import.Range("O:O"), y)
                                If result > 0 Then
                                    sales.Cells(RowNumber, ColLeft).Value = result
                                Else
                                End If
                                sales.Cells(RowNumber, ColRight + 1).Value = result1
                                If y = "BLF" Or y = "BAS" Then
                                    If y = "BLF" Then Region = "Belfast"
                                    ElseIf y = "BAS" Then Region = "Basingstoke"
                                    End If
                                    If y <> "BLF" And y <> "BAS" Then
                                    Region = y
                                End If
                             End If
                             sales.Cells(RowNumber, ColRight).Formula = "=SUMIFS(Table_PTQV02_PTQSOFT_SALES_ORDERS_Index3[Sales_day],Table_PTQV02_PTQSOFT_SALES_ORDERS_Index3[SALES_DATE],""" & x & """,Table_PTQV02_PTQSOFT_SALES_ORDERS_Index3[REGION_NAME],""*" & Region & "*"")"                
                    End With
                Next y
            Else
            End If
    End With                         
Next x
```

Comment: Have you tried to set a break point and step through it with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: I think your `ElseIf` is redundant, in the previous `If` statement you already reduced the possibilities to `"BLF" Or "BAS"` so why not use just `Else` ?

Comment: So, what is the value of `y` when it hits the `ElseIf`? Or better, does it hit the statement when the input is `"BAS"` and if not, why not? Maybe there is some white space in y.

Comment: Oh, and it seems that you are missing an `End If`

Comment: @Stefan the value of y is "BAS".  I also thought I was missing an "end if", but it kept giving me an "end if without block if" error...

Comment: Does this module have `Option Explicit` at the top?  If not, add it and see if any syntax errors surface.

Comment: @BrianMStafford yes, it does

Comment: If you have If statement all on one line it is considered closed i.e. f y = "BLF" Then Region = "Belfast" is closed and doesn't require an End If and so you cannot use an ElseIf after. You must split across lines as per Stafford's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This block of code is invalid:

```
   If y = "BLF" Or y = "BAS" Then
       If y = "BLF" Then Region = "Belfast"
       ElseIf y = "BAS" Then Region = "Basingstoke"
       End If
       If y <> "BLF" And y <> "BAS" Then
       Region = y
   End If
```

Try structuring it like this:

```
   If y = "BLF" Or y = "BAS" Then
       If y = "BLF" Then
          Region = "Belfast"
       ElseIf y = "BAS" Then
          Region = "Basingstoke"
       End If
   ElseIf y <> "BLF" And y <> "BAS" Then
       Region = y
   End If
```

Or you could drastically simplify it like this:

```
   Region = y
   If y = "BLF" Then Region = "Belfast"
   If y = "BAS" Then Region = "Basingstoke"
```

Comment: This is correct - marked as answer. 

I did say it would be something obvious! 

I am more used to SQL, where you can put "then" on the same line.

Comment: @Statsanalyst you absolutely can put `Then xyz` on the same line - except when you do that you're writing an `If` *statement*, and so there's no *block* involved, and therefore no `End If` is needed (and putting one is, in fact, illegal). When you put `xyz` on the line *after* `Then`, you're writing an `If` *block*, and `End If` is *required*. You can't mix-and-match syntaxes - pick one: statement, or block.

Comment: FWIW if there's only ever 2 branches, the *drastically simplified* code could be further simplified to `Region = IIf(y = "BLF", "Belfast", "Basingstoke")`, but IMO a dictionary mapping 3-character keys to full names would be much cleaner.

Comment: @Mat'sMug not a bad idea, but there are multiple branches.  I have changed the names from the real depots to protect proprietary info.  The significance of the two real depots is that they are the only two for which the three-digit codes aren't contained in the full name - e.g. "BLF" isn't in "Belfast", whereas, e.g., "EDI" is in "Edinburgh".  But when I changed the names, I stupidly chose "BAS" for "Basingstoke", and forgot that that does contain "BAS"!

Comment: @Statsanalyst look into how `Scripting.Dictionary` could help you map the values here. Alternatively you could use a keyed `Collection`, too, and then do `Region = regionMap(y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the conditions simple and write it like below :

```
If y = "BLF" Or y = "BAS" Then
   If y = "BLF" Then
      Region = "Belfast"
   Else
      Region = "Basingstoke"
   End If
Else
    Region = y     
End If
```